# Media Notification not working in Oreo

Tags: android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo

What modifications do i have to do to the below code to make notifications work in API 26+ cause Oreo requires channel and this code is a bit messy. I tried implimenting the channels but didn't work maybe did something wrong so I'm posting the unaltered code without any channel or any other modifications.

```
public class MediaPlayerService extends Service implements PlayerFragment.onPlayPauseListener {

private MediaSessionManager m_objMediaSessionManager;
private MediaSession m_objMediaSession;
private MediaController m_objMediaController;
private FFmpegMediaPlayer m_objMediaPlayer;
private NotificationManager notificationManager;

private ServiceCallbacks serviceCallbacks;

Intent startIntent;

PlayerFragment pFragment;

private boolean isSwipable = false;

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public MediaPlayerService getService() {
        // Return this instance of MyService so clients can call public methods
        return MediaPlayerService.this;
    }
}

public void setCallbacks(ServiceCallbacks callbacks) {
    serviceCallbacks = callbacks;
    pFragment = serviceCallbacks.getPlayerFragment();
    if (pFragment != null)
        pFragment.mCallback7 = this;
    if (m_objMediaSessionManager == null) {
        initMediaSessions();
    }
    handleIntent(startIntent);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    startIntent = intent;
    return new LocalBinder();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    try {
        pFragment = ((HomeActivity) PlayerFragment.ctx).getPlayerFragment();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (pFragment != null)
        pFragment.mCallback7 = this;

    if (m_objMediaSessionManager == null) {
        initMediaSessions();
    }
    handleIntent(intent);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent == null || intent.getAction() == null)
        return;

    String action = intent.getAction();

    if (m_objMediaController != null && action.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.ACTION_PLAY)) {
        m_objMediaController.getTransportControls().play();
    } else if (m_objMediaController != null && action.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.ACTION_PAUSE)) {
        m_objMediaController.getTransportControls().pause();
    } else if (m_objMediaController != null && action.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.ACTION_FAST_FORWARD)) {
        m_objMediaController.getTransportControls().fastForward();
    } else if (m_objMediaController != null && action.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.ACTION_REWIND)) {
        m_objMediaController.getTransportControls().rewind();
    } else if (m_objMediaController != null && action.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.ACTION_PREVIOUS)) {
        m_objMediaController.getTransportControls().skipToPrevious();
    } else if (m_objMediaController != null && action.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.ACTION_NEXT)) {
        m_objMediaController.getTransportControls().skipToNext();
    } else if (m_objMediaController != null && action.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.ACTION_STOP)) {
        m_objMediaController.getTransportControls().stop();
    }
}

private void buildNotification(Notification.Action action) {

    Notification.MediaStyle style = new Notification.MediaStyle();
    style.setShowActionsInCompactView(1);
    style.setMediaSession(m_objMediaSession.getSessionToken());

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MediaPlayerService.class);
    intent.setAction(Constants.ACTION_STOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, 0);

    String artist;

    if (pFragment != null && pFragment.localIsPlaying) {
        artist = pFragment.localTrack.getArtist();
    } else {
        artist = "";
    }

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    Bitmap bmp = null;

    try {
        bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) pFragment.selected_track_image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (bmp == null) {
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_default);
    }

    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setStyle(style)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setDeleteIntent(pendingIntent)
            .addAction(generateAction(R.drawable.ic_skip_previous_notif, "Previous", Constants.ACTION_PREVIOUS))
            .addAction(action)
            .addAction(generateAction(R.drawable.ic_skip_next_notif, "Next", Constants.ACTION_NEXT))
            .setContentTitle(pFragment.selected_track_title.getText())
            .setContentText(artist)
            .setLargeIcon(bmp)
            .build();

    notification.contentIntent = pendingNotificationIntent;
    notification.priority = Notification.PRIORITY_MAX;

    if (isSwipable || (pFragment.mMediaPlayer != null && pFragment.mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())) {
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    }


    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    try {
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    updateMediaSession();

}

private Notification.Action generateAction(int icon, String title, String intentAction) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MediaPlayerService.class);
    intent.setAction(intentAction);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, 0);
    return new Notification.Action.Builder(icon, title, pendingIntent).build();
}

void updateMediaSession() {
    if (pFragment != null) {
        m_objMediaSession.setFlags(MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);

        MediaMetadata.Builder metadataBuilder = new MediaMetadata.Builder();
        if (pFragment.localIsPlaying) {
            if (pFragment.localTrack != null) {
                metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, pFragment.localTrack.getTitle());
                metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, pFragment.localTrack.getArtist());
            }
        } else {
            if (pFragment.track != null) {
                metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, pFragment.track.getTitle());
                metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, "");
            }
        }
        if (((BitmapDrawable) pFragment.selected_track_image.getDrawable()).getBitmap() != null) {
            try {
                metadataBuilder.putBitmap(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, ((BitmapDrawable) pFragment.selected_track_image.getDrawable()).getBitmap());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        m_objMediaSession.setMetadata(metadataBuilder.build());
        PlaybackState.Builder stateBuilder = new PlaybackState.Builder();
        stateBuilder.setActions(PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY | PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE | PlaybackState.ACTION_PAUSE | PlaybackState.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT | PlaybackState.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS);
        try {
            if (pFragment.mMediaPlayer != null) {
                stateBuilder.setState(!pFragment.mMediaPlayer.isPlaying() ? PlaybackState.STATE_PAUSED : PlaybackState.STATE_PLAYING, PlaybackState.PLAYBACK_POSITION_UNKNOWN, 1.0f);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        m_objMediaSession.setPlaybackState(stateBuilder.build());
        m_objMediaSession.setActive(true);
    }
}

private void initMediaSessions() {

    if (pFragment != null) {
        pFragment.mCallback7 = this;

        m_objMediaPlayer = pFragment.mMediaPlayer;
        m_objMediaSessionManager = (MediaSessionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_SESSION_SERVICE);
        m_objMediaSession = new MediaSession(getApplicationContext(), "sample session");

        m_objMediaSession.setFlags(MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);

        MediaMetadata.Builder metadataBuilder = new MediaMetadata.Builder();
        if (pFragment.localIsPlaying) {
            if (pFragment.localTrack != null) {
                metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, pFragment.localTrack.getTitle());
                metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, pFragment.localTrack.getArtist());
            }
        } else {
            if (pFragment.track != null) {
                metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, pFragment.track.getTitle());
                metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, "");
            }
        }
        if (pFragment.selected_track_image != null && pFragment.selected_track_image.getDrawable() != null) {
            if (((BitmapDrawable) pFragment.selected_track_image.getDrawable()).getBitmap() != null) {
                metadataBuilder.putBitmap(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, ((BitmapDrawable) pFragment.selected_track_image.getDrawable()).getBitmap());
            }
        }


        m_objMediaSession.setMetadata(metadataBuilder.build());
        PlaybackState.Builder stateBuilder = new PlaybackState.Builder();
        stateBuilder.setActions(PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY | PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE | PlaybackState.ACTION_PAUSE | PlaybackState.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT | PlaybackState.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS);
        try {
            if (pFragment.mMediaPlayer != null) {
                stateBuilder.setState(!pFragment.mMediaPlayer.isPlaying() ? PlaybackState.STATE_PAUSED : PlaybackState.STATE_PLAYING, PlaybackState.PLAYBACK_POSITION_UNKNOWN, 1.0f);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        m_objMediaSession.setPlaybackState(stateBuilder.build());

        m_objMediaSession.setActive(true);
        m_objMediaController = m_objMediaSession.getController();
        m_objMediaSession.setCallback(new MediaSession.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onPlay() {
                super.onPlay();
                try {
                    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "onPlay");
                    PlayerFragment pFrag = pFragment;
                    if (pFrag != null) {
                        if (!pFrag.isStart) {
                            pFrag.togglePlayPause();
                        }
                        pFrag.isStart = false;
                        buildNotification(generateAction(R.drawable.ic_pause_notif, "Pause", Constants.ACTION_PAUSE));
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPause() {
                super.onPause();
                try {
                    PlayerFragment pFrag = pFragment;
                    if (pFrag != null) {
                        pFrag.togglePlayPause();
                        buildNotification(generateAction(R.drawable.ic_play_notif, "Play", Constants.ACTION_PLAY));
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSkipToNext() {
                super.onSkipToNext();
                try {
                    if (pFragment != null) {
                        pFragment.onCallbackCalled(2);
                        final Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                buildNotification(generateAction(R.drawable.ic_pause_notif, "Pause", Constants.ACTION_PAUSE));
                            }
                        }, 100);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onSkipToPrevious() {
                super.onSkipToPrevious();
                try {
                    if (pFragment != null) {
                        pFragment.onCallbackCalled(3);
                        final Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                buildNotification(generateAction(R.drawable.ic_pause_notif, "Pause", Constants.ACTION_PAUSE));
                            }
                        }, 100);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFastForward() {
                super.onFastForward();
                Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "onFastForward");
                if (pFragment != null)
                    pFragment.mCallback.onComplete();
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        buildNotification(generateAction(R.drawable.ic_pause_notif, "Pause", Constants.ACTION_PAUSE));
                    }
                }, 100);
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewind() {
                super.onRewind();
                Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "onRewind");
                if (pFragment != null)
                    pFragment.mCallback.onPreviousTrack();
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        buildNotification(generateAction(R.drawable.ic_pause_notif, "Pause", Constants.ACTION_PAUSE));
                    }
                }, 100);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStop() {
                super.onStop();

            }

            @Override
            public void onSeekTo(long pos) {
                super.onSeekTo(pos);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSetRating(Rating rating) {
                super.onSetRating(rating);
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    m_objMediaSession.release();
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

@Override
public void onPlayPause() {
    if (pFragment.mMediaPlayer != null && pFragment.mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        buildNotification(generateAction(R.drawable.ic_pause_notif, "Pause", Constants.ACTION_PAUSE));
    } else {
        buildNotification(generateAction(R.drawable.ic_play_notif, "Play", Constants.ACTION_PLAY));
    }
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    try {
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.cancel(1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that clearing the app cache (I did not clear data, just cache) and restarting your phone restores notifications. I was previously also getting the "enable notifications" screen as mentioned by previous posts. Now notifications work as expected.